# Image made through Toolkit returns -1 as width,height

Tags: java, toolkit

```
java.awt.Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
try {
   java.awt.Image img,ig;
   img = kit.getImage("/home/aditya/Pictures/tile.png");
   ig =
      javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(
         new java.io.File("/home/aditya/Pictures/tile.png"));
}
int w  = img.getWidth(null);
int wp = ig .getWidth(null);
int h  = img.getHeight(null);
int hp = ig .getHeight(null);
System.out.println(wp+" "+hp+" "+w+" "+h);
```

Always gives this output

```
59 64 -1 -1
```

i.e. width,height of image created through toolkit always returns -1.

Any idea ?

Comment: The image loaded by the toolkit may not have been realised yet.  The toolkit will load the image in the background and allow the application to continue running while it does so. Try using an ImageObserver to waitFor the image to be loaded and try again

Comment: in my actually program i am drawing both the images in a panel..both images loads properly and i am writing the draw code after this code.

Comment: The images draw correctly (presumably) because you are passing a reference of the panel to the drawImage method. The panel is a ImageObserver. This means that when the image becomes available, the panel is able to repaint itself

Answer (score 1):

Loading of images using awt is asynchronous.

[Look at this tutorial](http://underpop.online.fr/j/java/help/java-loading-images.html.gz).

```
class test extends Component
{
    test()
    {
        /* Get the toolkit from this Component */
        Toolkit t = getToolkit();
        /* Begin a retrieval of a remote image */
        Image   i = t.getImage( "https://cdn.southampton.ac.uk/assets/imported/transforms/site/depth/Action_BackgroundImage/E8813999F2F94220B91699A33F794636/201117_syndicut_southamptonUni_Homepage_banner.png_SIA_JPG_fit_to_width_FULL.jpg");
        /* Create a new MediaTracker linked to this Component */
        MediaTracker m = new MediaTracker( this );
        /* Add the loading image to the MediaTracker,
           with an ID of 1 */
        m.addImage( i, 1 );
        /* Explicitly wait for the image to load */
        try
        {
            m.waitForAll();
        }
        /* Catch the exception */
        catch( InterruptedException e )
        {
            System.out.println("Loading of the image was interrupted" );
        }

        /* Check the status */
        if( m.status() & MediaTracker.LOADING )
            System.out.println("Still Loading - oops, we should never be here!");
        if( m.status() & MediaTracker.ABORTED )
            System.out.println("Loading of image aborted");
        if( m.status() & MediaTracker.ERRORED )
            System.out.println("Image was errored");
        if( m.status() & MediaTracker.COMPLETE )
            System.out.println("Image load complete!");
    }
}
```

Comment: in my actually program i am drawing both the images in a panel..both images loads properly. then also it toolkit genrated image returns -1

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using null for getWidth, you can use an ImageObserver.

```
ImageObserver a = new ImageObserver(){
                      imageUpdate​(Image img, int infoflags, int x, int y, int width, int height){
        System.out.println("After loading: " + x + ", " + y + ", " +width + ", " + height);
    }
}
```

Then when you get the width, you'll get -1 the first call, but the observer will be notified when it is changed. "if the width is not yet known, this method returns -1 and the specified ImageObserver object is notified later"